# Using Androidjavaobject in C# Two-dimensional Arrays transfer to Java is possible? And returns too

Tags: java, c#, android, arrays

I am working on a Unity3D & Android cross-platform project.

I want improve the performance, so I changed my code.

This is my first attempt.

In C#

```
string str = JO.Call<string> ("GetDevices");
```

in Java

```
public String GetDevices() {
      String devices = "";
      /* ... */
      return devices;
}
```

It works, but I don't like this.

So, I changed it like this:

In C#

```
string[,] str = new string[deviceNum,2];
str = JO.Call<string[,]> ("GetDevices");
```

In Java

```
public String[][] GetDevices() {
    String[][] devices = {{""}};
    /* ... */
    return devices;
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

---

This is my first attempt log :

```
 I/Unity: Exception: JNI: System.Array in n dimensions is not allowed
                                        at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetSignature (System.Object obj) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                        at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetSignature[String[,]] (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                        at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID[String[,]] (IntPtr jclass, System.String methodName, System.Object[] args, Boolean isStatic) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                        at UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetMethodID[String[,]] (IntPtr jclass, System.String methodName, System.Object[] args, Boolean isStatic) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                        at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._Call[String[,]] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                        at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Call[String[,]] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

And I tried "Pef" way and log like this

```
 07-18 10:21:58.318 18999-19055/? I/Unity: Exception: JNI: Unknown generic array type 'System.String[]'
                                        at UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.ConvertFromJNIArray[String[][]] (IntPtr array) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                        at UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.ConvertFromJNIArray[String[][]] (IntPtr array) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                        at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._Call[String[][]] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                                        at UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.Call[String[][]] (System.String methodName, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: @stefanobaghino Thank you stefanobaghino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve this problem

in c#

```
 string[] devicesstr = new string[deviceNum*2];
 devicesstr = tcamJO.Call<string[]> ("GetDevices");
```

in java

```
 public String[] GetDevices() {
 String[] devices = {"",};
 /* ... */
     devices = new String[cameraIds.length * 2];
     int j =0;
     for (int i = 0; i < cameraIds.length + 1; i += 2) {
           devices[i] = cameraIds[j++];
           /* .... */
           if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
               devices[i+1] = "1";
           } else {
               devices[i+1] = "0";
           }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a multidimensional array in your C# code which is different from an array of arrays as you are using in your java code.

For more details on the difference look here: [What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)

You could try:

```
string[][] str = new string[2][];
str[0] = new string[deviceNum];
str[1] = new string[deviceNum];
str = JO.Call<string[][]> ("GetDevices");
```

And pay attention to the order of the array dimensions.

Comment: If you only get back data you can omit the 2nd and 3rd line.

Comment: Thank you Pef, i tried your advice. But isn't solved.